# Unresolved Reference Java

Tags: android-studio, android-intent, android-activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
lateinit var playbutton : Button

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    playbutton = findViewById(R.id.play_button)
    playbutton.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this,Frame::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

}
Showing Error Unreolved Reference Java
my Imports :

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
```

I am starting another Activity From The Mainactivity and android studio is Showing This Error .

Comment: Can you please post in which line you are getting the error. May be you need to import `Frame` class.

Comment: @SwaminathanV val intent = Intent(this,Frame::class.java) showing unresolved Reference Java

Comment: Have you tried importing the package in which `Frame.kt` belongs ?